# Unable to deploy golang webapp on Ubuntu 22.04 server with ISPConfig 3.11

Tags: apache2, webapps, golang

As the server is equiped with ISPConfig control panel and Apache2 is installed during the ISPConfig installation, I am not able to deploy golang webapp on the `/web` directory (tried both `go run webapp.go` as well as `go build webapp.go` and then run `./webapp`).

I am not sure if it is related to the apache2 web server which is the web server of the server or something else. I already tried activating the CGI option on the website's in ISPConfig and moved the executable file into `/cgi-bin` directory with no luck.

The server serves multiple websites and apache is used for running wordpress on some of them.

Appreciate your help.